# C++ class members pointers vs simple values memory management

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, struct

I am newbie. I have some questions regarding memory management.

Consider that I have the following class

```
class SomeClass : public AbstractClass {
private:
   SomeStruct *m_struct_;
public:
    const SomeStruct *get_struct();
};
```

And `SomeStruct`

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    std::vector<double> coefficients;    
    double dimension;              
};
```

Here is the constructor

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeStruct configuration) {
    this->m_struct= &configuration;
}
```

or it could be

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeStruct* configuration) {
    this->m_struct= configuration;
}
```

What I am doing now is the following code

```
SomeStruct config = get_struct_somewhere();
SomeClass *obj = new SomeClass(config);
```

So as you can see above. I am using the `get_struct_somewhere`, it returns `SomeStruct` and not a pointer `SomeStruct*`.

Here is how I understand memory allocations in this case.

1. The function `get_struct_somewhere` returns the struct, but not a pointer to the struct. That means that locally this function allocates a struct in `Stack`, but when it returns it it makes a copy of the struct allocated in `Stack`.
2. Therefore I am getting the copy of the struct. But again after I get it it is still allocated in the stackframe of a function where this code is executed

> ```
>   SomeStruct config = get_struct_somewhere();
>   SomeClass *obj = new SomeClass(config);
> ```

3. In case of using the following constructor

> ```
>  SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeStruct configuration) {
>      this->m_struct= &configuration;
>  }
> ```

It copies this struct again, but when I am leaving the constructor's scope this variable will be lost.

4. Another constructor

> ```
>  SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeStruct* configuration) {
>      this->m_struct= configuration;
>  }
> ```

As far as I am getting the struct using `get_struct_somewhere` this variable also will be lost but in the outer scope

5. So in this case I have only one option

> ```
> SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeStruct configuration) {
>     this->m_struct= configuration;
>  }
> ```

In this case this variable will be copied three times. And the struct will be assigned to object and therefore will be copied to the `Heap`. And will be available as long as the object lives.

Could you please confirm or deny my understanding and explain why.

Also I want to know the best way for managing objects for similar cases, how should I allocate objects, pass them to keep my memory clean.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem knowledgeable enough about **C++** to not tag **C**, right?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, sorry for that, I added C tag automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right gist of it. To avoid these problems, the simplest solution is to make the member `SomeStruct m_struct_;` (i.e. not a pointer).

If you really want to have a pointer then make the member be `std::unique_ptr<SomeStruct> m_struct_;` or `std::shared_ptr<SomeStruct> m_struct_;`, depending on whether or not you want to "shallow copy" the member when your class is copied.

In these cases you need to take care designing your constructor to make it clear when (or whether) the caller is handing off ownership, so the caller can avoid making memory allocation mistakes.

Also, it would be preferable for `get_struct()` to return `SomeStruct const&` if it is not intended that the caller of this function takes on ownership of the struct.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, yes I've exactly meant that I need to change the member to simple variable from the pointer)

Answer (score 0):

2) The object is returned by value (which is copied in the caller stack, as you said) but then destroyed as it exits the scope of `get_struct_somewhere()`

5) You can't assign `SomeStruct configuration` to `SomeStruct *m_struct_`. You would have to assign it as a pointer, and be left with a dangling pointer by the time the constructor scope ends (don't want that), or turn `SomeStruct *m_struct_` into `SomeStruct *m_struct_` and make another copy, as you say.

Two things to do:

- Use std::unique_ptr to wrap your type, and let the unique_ptr handle memory deallocation for you
- Implement a [move constructor/assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) for your type if you are
  concerned about cost of copy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and provided solutions. I have just omitted mentioning type change.